# How to remove component name from URL?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, view, controller

I am making a custom component and I dont want the name of the component on the URL when component loads.

The URL is coming like this :

http://example.com/component/componentName/view=viewName

But I don't want to show **[component/componentName]** in the URL.

Is there any way to hide this??
Or any method by which I can do this??

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275317/hide-component-name-from-urls-in-joomla)

Comment: thanks a lot Lodder for the help and i am using the same method for this but i have many redirection on the same component and when i redirect and new URL generates, again the component name appear on the URL.

Comment: Did you figure this out? running into the same problem using component-creator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .htaccess In joomla with apache rewrite feature.

1. Rename the file htaccess.txt to .htaccess In root joomla folder;
2. Enable Apache rewrite In global configuration In joomla admin area.

Answer (score 1):

Let you know Goto backend -> Menus -> Add new menu item -> Here you can create the one menuitem with title and alias that alias name display in url.
**(or)** 
Try like this Goto backend -> System -> Global configuration -> Turn on the sef url.

Comment: thanks for the help but i have many redirection on the same component and when i redirect and new URL generates, again the component name appear on the URL